# Get notification icon using an accessibility service

Tags: android, notifications, accessibilityservice

Is there any way to get icons of system notifications?
I can get a notification parcel with Accessibility service. I can even get the id of the icon from it, but I am stuck there. I have no idea how to use the id to get the actual bitmap so I can display it, because it is not from my apk.

Here is my code so far:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d("onAccessibilityEvent");
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
            if (event.getParcelableData() instanceof Notification) {
                Notification notification = (Notification) event.getParcelableData();

                Log.d("ticker: " + notification.tickerText);
                Log.d("icon: " + notification.icon);
                Log.d("largeIcon: " + notification.largeIcon);

            }

            Log.d("notification: " + event.getText());
        }
    }
```

trying to use this id results in

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0200ad

Answer (score 4):

So I managed to accomplish this by searching for the first ImageView in the RemoteViews

```
extractImage(notification.contentView); 
...
      private void extractImage(RemoteViews views) {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            View view = views.apply(getApplicationContext(), ll);
            drawable = searchForBitmap(view);
            Log.d("Drawable: " + drawable);
        }

        private Drawable searchForBitmap(View view) {
            if (view instanceof ImageView) {
                return ((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
            }

            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
                for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    Drawable result = searchForBitmap(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
                    if (result != null) {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

See if this works:

`String mPackageName = event.getPackageName();

Context remotePackageContext = context.createPackageContext(mPackageName, 0);

Drawable icon = remotePackageContext.getResources().getDrawable(mIcon);`

Comment: this is just what i was looking for! Thanks for posting this