# Set ImageView drawable using AccessibilityService in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16258120/5193581) code to get the icon of the posted notification. This is my `NotificationService`:

```
public class NotificationService extends AccessibilityService {
About mAbout = new About();
public static Drawable drawable;
...

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
        Parcelable data = event.getParcelableData();
        if (data instanceof Notification) {
            Notification notification = (Notification) data;

            extractImage(notification.contentView);
            mAbout.setNotification(drawable);
        }
    }
  }
...

}
```

Here is `About.java`

```
public class About extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView testView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    testView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testView);
}

public void setNotification(Drawable drawable) {
    testView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

}

I've enabled the service in Settings > Accessibility but when I receive a notification my app crashes because of this line: `mAbout.setNotification(drawable);`

Any help is appreciated. Also can I use this same method of getting the icon using the new NotificationListenerService?

Comment: have you inited your drawable? or is it null?

Comment: It is initialized using `extractImage(notification.contentView);`